# Remote DOS Git repo and local unix repo

Tags: git

I am tracking remote repo which have files with dos endings (CRLF). I want to get local one which uses just LF, but I do not want to introduce changes in endings since I need to regularly merge with upstream repo. Any advises?

Answer (score 1):

You should set:

> core.autocrlf=true

See this page:
http://help.github.com/line-endings/

Comment: This will fix it if I would be using Windows and having problems with LF ending. I have problems with CRLF coming from remote repo. So I need opposite to what autocrlf doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try `core.autocrlf input`. Also on each repo, you can set the native line ending so the autocrlf will do what you expect on each FS.